# Cypher merge query creates new nodes instead of merging

Tags: neo4j, cypher

So I'm trying to figure out why this keeps creating new nodes instead creating relationships to the existing nodes. Using this example: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/unwind/

I feel like my query is basically the same thing. But as you can see below, instead of relating 222 and 333 both to 111, it creates 2 nodes as 111

#### Parameters

```
:params {components:[{targetId: "111", dependencyId: "222"},{targetId: "111", dependencyId:"333"}]}
```

#### Query

```
UNWIND $components AS component
MERGE (dependency:Component {Id: component.dependencyId })
MERGE (dependency)<-[:DEPENDS_ON]-(target:Component {Id: component.targetId })
RETURN dependency, target
```

One thing I noticed is that if I run the following query twice, it doesn't create the duplicate which seems to contradict what's happening in the UNWIND query above:

```
MERGE (c:Component {Id: "111"})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second MERGE query is trying to match using the whole pattern.

Once the query is executed again for the second entry on your list of components, it is not just matching to `(: Component {Id: "111"})`, but to `(: Component {Id: "333"})<-[:DEPENDS_ON]-(: Component {Id: "111"})` instead. Since the said pattern does not exist yet, the node for 111 is created again.

For 111 to not be created again, you need to add a MERGE query for that node alone.

```
UNWIND $components AS component
MERGE (dependency:Component {Id: component.dependencyId })
MERGE (target:Component {Id: component.targetId })
MERGE (dependency)<-[:DEPENDS_ON]-(target)
RETURN dependency, target
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I actually came to the same conclusion late last night! There were some other issues I ran into where it wasn't merging the new info as other instances of the query were coming through but I ended up working it out.